# Cartodb map style changes when clearing view

Tags: carto, cartocss

I'm losing the custom settings of my map when I perform simple filtering analysis and "Create Dataset from Query".

Here's what I'm doing:

1. I've created a map where I've specified my color scheme, updated the Info Window with the fields I want visible and update the legend. I then Publish the map.
2. In the DataView, I filter my data and "Create Dataset from Query"
3. I return to the MapView and the map retains my customization of the Info Windo, color scheme and legend.
4. There is an option to "Create Dataset from Query" or to "Clear View" in the MapView.  If "Clear View", I lose all my custom settings (Color scheme, no fields selected in Info Window and legend disappears)

I thought when I customized my map then Published it, every time I would "Clear View" the map would return to what I've saved?

Comment: I have been unable to duplicate the problem as you describe it. However, When you "Create Dataset from Query", and new table is created with a new map view with the default settings. Your original dataset is still in "your datasets", and if you select it and click "Map View" your map settings will have been retained.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Yes, I understand that if I select "Map View" that the new queried dataset will have default settings.  However, if I return to my "Dashboard" and select my original map project, it is there that I have lost my Info Window fields, color scheme, etc.